# Having 2 fields in 1 where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

How to have 2 fields in 1 where conditions?

```
WHERE id = '2' AND id = '3'
```

Is this possible? My query keep on getting zero result, but the fact that 2 id combined is having more than 10 row.

Comment: A column can never be both 2 and 3 at the same time. Do you want `id='2' OR id='3'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can one column have two distinct values at the same time? It can't. But there can be different values in different rows. To find these rows use `OR`:

```
WHERE id = '2' OR id = '3'
```

Answer (score 2):

you could be looking for an OR instead of an AND.

Try this:

WHERE id = '2' OR id = '3';

Answer (score 2):

A column can never be both 2 *and* 3 at the same time. I suspect you want `id='2' OR id='3'`. And if that's what you're doing, you can shorten it like this:

```
WHERE id IN ('2','3')
```

And since those are both numeric values, you might even want this:

```
WHERE id IN (2,3)
```